# How to add variable at the start of the URL in Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-route

I am trying here to create url, like:

```
/admin/login
/moderator/login
```

both the request would be served by same controller & action made for login, i.e. `/account/login/<type>`

Currently, all I am able to make the following URL:

`/login/admin`

`/login/moderator`

My current config file looks like the following:

```
resources.router.routes.login.route = "login/:type"
resources.router.routes.login.defaults.controller = "account"
resources.router.routes.login.defaults.action = "login"
```

I can't figure out, on how to put the `type` variable at the start of URL, I tried it but it gives server error.
**edit**

I got this done, but can't understand why this didn't work earlier:

```
resources.router.routes.login.route = ":type/login"
resources.router.routes.login.defaults.controller = "account"
resources.router.routes.login.defaults.action = "login"
```

**edit**

Is it possible to make this arrangement more flexible, so that:
`/login` => `/admin/login`

I am not looking for solution via .htaccess

Comment: You are not looking for htaccess, how about bootstrap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following to your Bootstrap.php

```
function _initRoutes() {
    $front_controller = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $router = $front_controller->getRouter();

    $router->addRoute('login', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
        '/:type/login', array('controller' => 'account', 'action' => 'login')
    ));
}
```

from your loginAction()
use:

```
$this->getRequest()->getParam('type');
```

Simple?

Comment: thanks for your answer here, can you provide me something that could help me redirect `/login` => `/admin/login`

Comment: Though i was able to get solutions for this by application.ini, i didn't understand why this didn't worked earlier

Comment: From Login to /admin/login can be bit tricky! I would suggest redirecting `/login` to say a test controller and test action which would redirect to `/admin/login`. However if you want admin as in Controller admin and Login as in Action Login then, I can edit my answer for you. PS: If this resolves your query, how about a tick next to my answer? :P