# Using Zend translate in Bootstrap.php

Tags: zend-framework

I have several routes defined in Zend's Bootstrap.php that I want to translate with Zend's translate function:

```
$trans = new Zend_View_Helper_Translate();
$router->addRoute(
  'myroute',
  new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(':lang/'.$trans->translate('mytitle').'/',
    array(
      'module' => 'default',
      'controller' => 'index',
      'action' => 'statistics'
    )
  )
);
```

The helper itself seems to work (doesn't throw an exception or error) but always returns mytitle instead of the actual translation which is defined in the language file (I checked - the language files work in the view).

**How can I get the translate function to work in the Bootstrap.php file?**

Comment: Try doing this in a plugin instead of the bootstrap.

Comment: How are you passing params? check in the array. I can see the error already! I am tempted to answer but, you are JUST THERE......... REACH OUT!

Comment: @KarmicDice I don't see a problem with the parameters of the `Zend_Controller_Router_Route`. It works fine except for the translation...

Comment: @DylanSumiskum Can you explore that idea a little more, please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12196330/how-to-add-variable-at-the-start-of-the-url-in-zend-framework/12197379#12197379 got the logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that you needs to load translations before you use it.
Load routing translations like:

```
$router->setDefaultTranslator($yourTranslator);
```

Best how to use routing translations is adding '@' before a word you want to translate f.e.:

```
$router->addRoute(
  'myroute',
  new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(':lang/@mytitle/',
    array(
      'module' => 'default',
      'controller' => 'index',
      'action' => 'statistics'
    )
  )
);
```